# Image in database with Symfony 3

Tags: image, symfony

I'm here become I don't know how to send a picture in DataBase, I did this entity:

```
class Image
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $url;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="alt", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $alt;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nom", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nom;
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://dancostinel.com/blog/web/blog/how-to-create-upload-functionality-using-symfony3) blog post.

Answer (score 0):

Your Image is just a file, your are going to store your file in a chosen folder and handle the upload to this folder with the help of the documentation : http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html.

So, in 2 words what happen ? 
1) You choose a folder 
2) You create a "service" that will upload your file into your folder
3) You store the name of your file in DB

Then if you want your file, you have his name in the db and you know in which folder to search.

Answer (score 0):

*This seems fair to assume you don't want to save a picture in the database but infos about an uploaded picture which is saved on the filesystem.*

---

## Simplify your life!

> Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to!

- Use the very good [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) for this.
- You will see the [VichImageType](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/form/vich_image_type.md) which you can use.

Note. An image is a file, see [How to upload files?](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html).

---

## Extra

You might want to take a good look at [LiipImagineBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html) to handle image manipulation and save you time.